# Django No URL to redirect to. Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model

Tags: python, django

Hi I am trying to create a blog using the Django webframework.

I get the error,

```
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.
```

> The urls.py is given below,

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    BlogListView,
    BlogDetailView,
    BlogCreateView,
    BlogUpdateView,
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    path('post/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

The models.py is given below,

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
MAX_LENGTH = 500


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_LENGTH)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    body = models.TextField()


def __str__(self):
    return self.title


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

> Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your indentation it looks as if your methods on the Post class are instead in the global scope. They should have the same indendation as the title, author and body field (i.e. 4 spaces/1 tab).

Comment: Hi Lucas , thanks for the quick reply. Yeah got it fixed after the functions are moved from global scope to it's class.